# Java7: What is some equivalent to specifing method references in a function call

Tags: java, java-7, method-reference

I'd like to write a method that invokes a specified method on an appropriate object.
The caveat is that I want to do this without changing the classes (e.g. implementing interfaces) from where I call the method.

I found what I was looking for in function pointers in C, but nothing for Java 7 yet.

Here some pseudo code:

```
public class A {
    ... constructor ...

    public String aToString(){
        return "A";
    }
}

public class B {
    ... constructor ...

    public String bToString(){
        return "B";
    }
}
/* T::<String>mymethod stands for "Method with identifier 'mymethod'
 * in Class T with return type String"
 */
public class ServiceClass {
    public static void genericToString(Collection<T> c, 
                                       MethodPointer T::<String>mymethod){
        for(int i=0,i<c.length,i++) {
            System.out.println(c.get(i).mymethod());

        }
    }

    public static void main(){
        ArrayList<A> listA = new ArrayList<A>();
        listA.add(new A());
        ServiceClass.genericToStringOutput(listA, A::<String>aToString);

        ArrayList<B> listB = new ArrayList<B>();
        listB.add(new B());
        ServiceClass.genericToStringOutput(listB, B::<String>bToString);
    }
}
```

Is there a way to achieve something like this in Java 7? The only constraint is that class A and B may not change.

Bonus points if types aren't hidden from the compiler.

Comment: You might want to switch to Java 8...

Comment: You can provider a `Function<T, String>`, either writing your own `Function` interface, or using [the one from Guava](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Function.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either make or choose a `Function` interface and pass that in:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

class A {
  public String aToString() {
    return "A";
  }
}

class B {
  public String bToString() {
    return "B";
  }
}

interface Function<IN, OUT> {
  OUT apply(IN input);//see guava for a prefab version of this
}

class ServiceClass {
  public static <T> void genericToString(Collection<T> c, Function<T, String> converter) {
    for (final T element : c) {
      System.out.println(converter.apply(element));
    }
  }

  public static void main() {
    List<A> listA = new ArrayList<>();
    listA.add(new A());
    ServiceClass.genericToString(listA, new Function<A, String>() {//the java 7 way
      @Override
      public String apply(final A input) {
        return input.aToString();
      }
    });

    List<B> listB = new ArrayList<>();
    listB.add(new B());
    ServiceClass.genericToString(listB, B::bToString);//the java 8 way
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for that solution. It works like a charm and is beautifully generic.

Answer (score 1):

In Java 7, equivalent code to having something like method references is the following:
First, we define an interface for our reference (nothing different compared to Java 8):

```
public interface MethodPointer<T> {
  String invoke(T arg);
}
```

Then we use it:

```
public class ServiceClass {
public static void genericToString(Collection<T> c, 
                                   MethodPointer<T> mymethod) {
    for(int i=0,i<c.length,i++) {
        System.out.println(mymethod.invoke(c.get(i)));
    }
}

public static void main() {
    ArrayList<A> listA = new ArrayList<A>();
    listA.add(new A());
    ServiceClass.genericToStringOutput(listA, new MethodPointer<A>() {
      @Override public String invoke(A arg) {
        return arg.toString();
      }
    });

    ArrayList<B> listB = new ArrayList<B>();
    listB.add(new B());
    ServiceClass.genericToStringOutput(listB, new MethodPointer<B>() {
      @Override public String invoke(B arg) {
        return arg.toDetailedString() // <- note that it's not just toString()
      }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: If all the types are know at compile time then what's the difference between doing `ServiceClass.genericToStringOutput(listA, new MethodPointer<A>() {
           @Override public String invoke(A arg) {
             return arg.aToString();
           } }
     );` versus plain old `for (A arg : listA) arg.aToString();`

Comment: In this case, we have separation of concerns: "genericToStringOutput" knows how to work with Collection and what "Output" means (i.e. System.out). On the other hand, MethodPointer knows HOW to convert a type to a String, and can be easily replaced without changing "genericToStringOutput".

Answer (score -2):

In Java 7, you are looking for something like

```
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;

public class ServiceClass<T> {

    public void genericToString(Collection<T> c, Method m)
        throws IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException{
        for(T e : c) {
            System.out.println(m.invoke(e));
        }
    }

    public static void main(){
        Method m;
        ArrayList<A> listA = new ArrayList<A>();
        listA.add(new A());
        m = new A().getClass().getMethod("aToString", new Class[]{});
        ServiceClass.genericToStringOutput(listA, m);

        ArrayList<B> listB = new ArrayList<B>();
        listB.add(new B());
        m = new B().getClass().getMethod("bToString", new Class[]{});
        ServiceClass.genericToStringOutput(listB, m);
    }
}
```

Comment: You *can* use reflection to do this, but you shouldn’t.  Reflection cannot be checked at compile-time and introduces a lot more potential for runtime errors.

Comment: So how to do it without reflection and without changing the definition of classes A and B?

Comment: Like the other answers suggest, create a separate interface similar to java.util.function.Function, and wrap a call to each class’s method in an anonymous implementation of that interface.